# First bash script not working

Tags: linux, bash, command-line

I'm following a tutorial on shell scripts.  The script I'm writing is supposed to take a name as an argument and print out "hello" followed by the argument.  I tried copying the code directly from the tutorial and it still hasn't worked

Here's the code:

```
$yourname=$1
echo "Hello $yourname"
```

And heres the error message I got:

```
$ bash hello.sh Mike   
hello.sh: line 1: =Mike: command not found
Hello
```

Comment: Make it `yourname=$1`.  No dollar before the variable name

Comment: `$yourname=$1` is wrong. 
A variable declaration in bash is `varname=VALUE`, the dollars are used to access defined variables.
Your statement should become `yourname=$1$` which defines a variable with name `yourname` and assigns it result of `$1` which is a lookup of the first given argument to your bash script.

Comment: Welcome to the weird bash world!

Comment: Add a shebang and then paste your script there: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Thanks guys, it's woking now.

Comment: *＋1* for finding the duplicate rather than answering.

Answer (score -1):

Vikas' comment is correct. You define vars in bash scripts without the dollar sign and then refer to them later using the dollar sign. That being the case, you should change `$yourname` to just `yourname` for that first occurrence. YOu might also consider adding a shebang to your script and making sure to set its permissions so it's executable:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
yourname=$1
echo "Hello $yourname"
```

Comment: Always great to get a downvote with no explanation 

Answer (score -1):

### $1 is Positional parameters, so you need to pass a positional parameter to this script while running the script.

```
$ cat hello.sh
yourname=$1
echo "Hello $yourname"

$ bash -x hello.sh Mike
+ yourname=Mike
+ echo 'Hello Mike'
Hello Mike
```

---

### Positional parameters

Arguments passed to the script from the command line: $0, $1, $2, $3 . . .

$0 is the name of the script itself, $1 is the first argument, $2 the second, $3 the third, and so forth. After $9, the arguments must be enclosed in brackets, for example, ${10}, ${11}, ${12}.